# Persisting ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I'm building a listview and getting it's data from Parse.com. At the moment, every time the app loads up it queries for new data from Parse.com, causing the whole listview to load.

I'd like a situation where the listview references a local datasource and only go to Parse.com if new data is available. Somewhat similar to what the instagram app does whereby when you load it up, the list view is already populated and would get updated if needed.

I have tried ParseQuery Cache policies but the behavior still stays the same. What would be the most efficient way of implementing this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Adapters can help you with your your problem. It is generally used for account and cloud synchronization. But there is no limitation using it.

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

> Synchronizing data between an Android device and web servers can make
>   your application significantly more useful and compelling for your
>   users. For example, transferring data to a web server makes a useful
>   backup, and transferring data from a server makes it available to the
>   user even when the device is offline. In some cases, users may find it
>   easier to enter and edit their data in a web interface and then have
>   that data available on their device, or they may want to collect data
>   over time and then upload it to a central storage area.
>
> Although you can design your own system for doing data transfers in
>   your app, you should consider using Android's sync adapter framework.
>   This framework helps manage and automate data transfers, and
>   coordinates synchronization operations across different apps. When you
>   use this framework, you can take advantage of several features that
>   aren't available to data transfer schemes you design yourself

You can access sample project here: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BasicSyncAdapter.zip

> **Note:** Sync adapters run asynchronously, so you should use them with the
>   expectation that they transfer data regularly and efficiently, but not
>   instantaneously. If you need to do real-time data transfer, you should
>   do it in an AsyncTask or an IntentService.